# Ошибка доступа к существующему файлу с полным доступом UBUNTU / CGI / python / os.execve

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, unix, cgi

предупреждение: Я полный 0 в Web, абсолютно не понимаю принципов работы и вариантов применения модели OSI в реальной жизни

Доброго времени суток, знатоки.
Решил я разобраться с созданием сайта для быстрого управления самописными программами на виртуальном выделенном сервере что бы каждый раз не лезть по ssh.
Под windows набросал проект на python CGI, проверил работоспособность, подключения через глобальную сеть. Всё было хорошо.
Перебросил проект на хост, выдал права 777 на каталог и все файлы в нём, запускаю, подключаюсь, вижу это:

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('185.6.127.40', 54228)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/http/server.py", line 1191, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/www/MyCMS/cgi-bin/index.py'
```

Странно, думаю, но ладно. Узнал о существовании apparmor, вырубил его терминальной командой найденной на форуме убунты:

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor && sudo systemctl disable apparmor && sudo systemctl mask apparmor
```

Эффекта ноль. Запустил из под юзера вместо рута, ошибка изменилась:

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('185.6.127.40', 52933)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/http/server.py", line 1191, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/www/MyCMS/cgi-bin/index.py'
```

### Внутренняя структура файла index.py:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3.11
    from auth import Auth
    
    index = "cgi-bin/html/index.html"
    auth = Auth()
    
    if auth.check_auth():
        with open(index, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            pattern = f.readlines()
    
        print("Content-type: text/html")
        for line in pattern:
            print(line)
    else:
        with open("cgi-bin/au", "w", encoding="utf-8") as af:
            r = auth.generate_code()
            af.writelines(str(r))
            print("Content-type: text/html\n")
            print(auth.pattern_success)
```

### Содержимое main.py:

```
import threading
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

server_address = ("", 80)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)


def server_run():
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = threading.Thread(target=server_run, daemon=True)
    cmd = ["start", "stop", "exit"]
    print("CGI server control")
    print("server commands")
    print(cmd)
    while True:
        command = input("enter command: ")
        try:
            if command == "start":
                process.start()
            if command == "stop":
                httpd.shutdown()
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Пробовал гуглить (там реально проблемы с файлами в основном), пробовал использовать BingGPT4.0 для решения проблемы и пару моментов он мне показал, но в итоге начал выдавать одно и тоже про права доступа, shebang, cgihttprequest и порты ниже 1024-го.

### И.. хз зачем, но вот вывод ls -la:

- структура дериктории MyCMS через:
- drwxrwxrwx 3 user user 4096 Feb  8 11:01 .
- drwxrwxrwx 5 user user 4096 Feb  8 11:00 ..
- drwxrwxrwx 5 user user 4096 Feb  9 15:31 cgi-bin
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  202 Feb  3 15:17 index.html
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  717 Feb  8 14:06 main.py
- структура дериктории cgi-bin:
- drwxrwxrwx 5 user user  4096 Feb  9 15:31 .
- drwxrwxrwx 3 user user  4096 Feb  8 11:01 ..
- drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Feb  8 15:54 **pycache**
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user     0 Feb  8 11:01 au
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user    46 Feb  8 11:01 auCode.json
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  5063 Feb  8 11:01 auth.py
- drwxrwxrwx 2 user user  4096 Feb  8 11:01 html
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   506 Feb  9 15:31 index.py
- drwxrwxrwx 2 user user  4096 Feb  8 11:01 js
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user    31 Feb  8 11:01 logs
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  1742 Feb  8 11:01 telebot_CMS.py
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   604 Feb  8 11:01 telebot_log.py
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 15065 Feb  8 11:00 telebot_main.py
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  1313 Feb  8 11:01 telegram_connect.py
- Структура дериктории html:
- drwxrwxrwx 2 user user 4096 Feb  8 11:01 .
- drwxrwxrwx 5 user user 4096 Feb  9 15:31 ..
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 1729 Feb  8 11:01 index.html
- -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 3791 Feb  8 11:01 telebot_CMS.html

## Итого:

- Права каталогов и всего содержимого /home/user/... —rwxrwxrwx;
- Язык python 3.11;
- Сервер CGI без фреймворков типа джанго/фласка. Торнадо вроде не совсем то, но его тоже не использовал
- ОС ubuntu 23.04
- sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/bin/python3.11 выполнял
- SELinux не установлен

UPD: попробовал перенести все файлы на каталог выше (результат не изменился, но вдруг..); установил nginx, передал права файлов пользователю www-data. Выдаёт ошибку HTTP 403 forbidden. Сам nginx в это время пишет:

```
2024/02/14 15:09:32 [error] 36931#36931: *30 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Cannot get script name, are DOCUMENT_ROOT and SCRIPT_NAME (or SCRIPT_FILENAME) set and is the script executable?" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.6.127.40, server: localhost, request: "GET /cgi-bin/index.py HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "146.0.79.237", referrer: "http://146.0.79.237/index.html"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил довольно странным способом, пояснения от знатоков были бы очень кстати.

Суть проблемы состояла в том, что все файлы скриптов я создавал на локальном ПК под Windows 10 в *PyCharm*, после переносил по `FTP` на удалённый сервер (под учётной записью `user`). Несмотря на то, что права у файлов `rwxrwxrwx`, а владелец и группа - `user:user`, *cgi* по какой-то причине считает, что прав недостаточно даже `root`-у.

Решение:

- запустил *cgi*-сервер
- удалил старые конфликтные файлы
- создал новые с соответствующими именами, где весь код прописал копипастом
- выдал права на выполнение
- исправил ошибки путей, руководствуясь ошибками сервера.